# vim pastes "9" after pressing the central button of the mouse

Tags: vim

After selecting a piece of text from a web page with the mouse, I'm trying to paste it into a file opened with vim, but when I press the central button of my mouse it just pastes "9" (with or without insert mode activated).

This is the output of :reg:

```
--- Registers ---
""   9
"0   9
"1   ^J
"-   9
"/   \s\+$
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: More importantly, what vim? Gvim? vim in a terminal? macvim?

Comment: If you're on Windows, you need to copy the text explicitly by typing control-C after selecting it. If you're on Linux or another Unix-like system, what happens if you type control-V before clicking?

Comment: Well, any web page..even a text copied on gedit (Im using xubuntu 10.04). Im using vim 7.2.330 in xterm. Besides, I dont have any problem pasting to the terminal prompt in the same way.

Comment: Type `:reg` in vim and see if one of the registers has "9" to help better diagnose what's going on. Information about this can be found at `:help xterm-copy-paste`.

Comment: @Conner I have added the output of `reg:` ..

Comment: vim is handling the mouse button and pasting from its default register, which is not connected to the X clipboard unless you have `:set clipboard` configured. To override it on a case-by-case basis, you can hold down the Shift key while pressing the mouse button. To disable it completely, `:set mouse=` (set the `mouse` option to the empty string).

Answer (score 0):

Create a file in your home directory  called `.vimrc` with this content:

```
set mouse=r
```